# Gradient Background

Tags: css, background

Hi guys i am making a website for my college project and i am not very good at using Dreamweaver CS6. I made my designs in photoshop and i am struggling to use my gradient background in my website. I have tried a couple of times to get it to work but it either repeats a lot of times or it fills up as certain amount of the page but cuts off. Any help would be appreciated thank you in advance.

Here is the CSS code

```
html body
{
background: linear-gradient(to top, #48E7A2 0%, #86C4ED 100%);
background-size:cover;

}
```

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Just with google you could find the answer [Background Gradient](https://www.google.com.co/search?q=css+background+gradient&oq=css+background+gradient&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i60j0l2.8778j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: There are loads... http://www.css3factory.com/linear-gradients/

Comment: Thanks for the help but the background is still repeating and its not one whole background ??

Comment: I have changed my code and added a DEMO (Jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1):

You can copy this code. From http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

You should use it on the `html{}` not on the `body{}` 
and add `height:100%;`

```
html {    
    height: 100%;
    background: #48e7a2; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #48e7a2 0%, #86c4ed 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#48e7a2), color-stop(100%,#86c4ed)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #48e7a2 0%,#86c4ed 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #48e7a2 0%,#86c4ed 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #48e7a2 0%,#86c4ed 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #48e7a2 0%,#86c4ed 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#48e7a2', endColorstr='#86c4ed',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/79FGa/1/)**

Comment: Thank you but th background still repeats over and over again,i have tried coding it like background-repeat:no-repeat but it still does not work

Comment: Did you check the DEMO? because it isnt repeating.., use the css code only on `html{}` not on the body

Comment: What is the demo and i copyed the exact code in and it still repeats

Comment: The demo is the link called DEMO, linking to a JsFiddle where you can see the demo.. did you use height:100% ?

Comment: Yeah i found the demo it works now i didnt change it from html body thats my bad but when i scroll down the page the colour looks weird in the sense that there is massive green line there

Comment: can you give me a link? to see what you mean?

Comment: Here you go, i also need the green at the bottom and the blue at the top i think that should be and easy fix file:///E:/College%20Work/Coursework/Jason/Travelynx/Website/index.html

Comment: yes just change the color codes on each css line.., and you have a offline project, so i cant see it..

Comment: nevermind, you need a server/domain/ something like filezilla.. can you make a screen shot of your screen? and upload it on a website?

Comment: uhhh can i send you an image through email ?

Comment: No im sorry, no personal contact like that. use a website like this https://imageshack.com/

Comment: Thank you for the help i have fixed it now as i just added some code to the body with margin top and bottom having 0px. You have helped me a lot thank you really apprecate it.